# Rails3 joins association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join, associations

I have trouble using joins in rails3.

There are two models :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :master,class_name: 'User'
end
```

The user model has 'name' field, when i'm trying to find some posts like this:

```
Post.joins(:master).where("master.name like '%mike%'")
```

It goes wrong, logs show as following:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'master.name' in 'where clause': SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `posts`.`master_id` WHERE (master.name like '%mike%')
```

i think maybe i'd give an alias name for users, but how?

i know it will work like this:

```
Post.joins("join users master on posts.master_id=master.id").where("master.name like '%mike%'")
```

But is there any better way? Any body kindly to help me solving this problem?

Comment: Try doing Post.master.where("name like '%mike%'") or Post.joins(:master).where("name like '%mike%'")

Comment: It do works, but if Post happend to have a 'name' attribute', it will fail again. anyway it fix my problems currently. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Post.joins(:master).where("users.name like '%mike%'")
```

Assuming you have `users` table for `User` model.

Comment: Yes, it will work when change master to users. i want to know whether there are any better way. :D

Comment: This is the way I usually do it whenever needed. May be there are some betters way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this line

```
has_many :posts
```

to your User class, it should be possible to get what you want with following query:

```
User.where("name like ?", "%mike").map(&:posts)
```